# How to implement a radiogroup in ExtJS7

Tags: extjs

I'm new to ExtJS and have some trouble implementing a radiogroup.

My structure is as follows:
I have a tab.Panel that loads form.Panel which is supposed to include a radiogroup amongst other things.

The file for the tab panel contains:

```
Ext.define('Test-Application.view.tab.Panel',{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.tab', 
    xtype: 'tab',
    fullscreen: true,

    controller: 'main',


    requires: [
        'Test-Application.view.form.TestForm'
    ],

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Testform',
            xtype: 'testform'
        }
    ]
});
```

And the file for the testform contains:

```
Ext.define('Test-Application.view.form.TestForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', 
    xtype: 'testform',

//    layout: 'form',


    items: [
        {
             xtype: 'radiogroup',
             label: 'Auto Layout:',
             items:
             [
                 { label: 'Item 1', value: 1},
                 { label: 'Item 2', value: 2, checked: true },
                 { label: 'Item 3', value: 3},
                 { label: 'Item 4', value: 4},
                 { label: 'Item 5', value: 5},
             ]
        }
    ]
});
```

All I get is the error "Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: widget.radiogroup".

Note that things like radiofields, textfields, comboboxes etc. seem to work just fine (though the radiofields don't work if I use layout: 'form' for some reason. They don't throw an error but simply don't show up).

Comment: For the first - You mixed `Classic` with `Modern` widgets.
Are you using `Classic` or `Modern` ? Parameter `fullscreen` is only in modern, component `Ext.tab.Panel` is only in classic.
For the second - you are trying to override existing widget - `tab`.

Comment: @norbeq ah yeah you're right about the classic element. That's from me fiddling around with various things. Changing it back to Ext.tabPanel, which is modern, and fixing the override issue doesn't seem to solve the problem though unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you used `extjs 7` instead of `extjs 6.7` ?

Check `alert(Ext.versions.ext.version)` to check the version.

`radiogroup` is only available from 7.0.

Using `radiogroup` in extjs `6.7` is not allowed and you will get error message (as you got)

> Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias:
>   widget.radiogroup

Here is example of working code in extjs 7.0.0:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            fullscreen:true,
            autoShow: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                    label: 'Auto Layout:',
                    items: [{
                        label: 'Item 1',
                        value: 1
                    }, {
                        label: 'Item 2',
                        value: 2,
                        checked: true
                    }, {
                        label: 'Item 3',
                        value: 3
                    }, {
                        label: 'Item 4',
                        value: 4
                    }, {
                        label: 'Item 5',
                        value: 5
                    }, ]
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: oh wow you're right. I only use Cmd 7.0.0.40 but extjs 6.7.0.210. That's what I get for trusting my coworker with setting up the system.

Comment: If my answer is correct, mark it as "This answer is useful" to let other people see that the question is solved.